# Sql Server Error - The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck on an error. Please help.

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 2 (".ሀ.Ȁ....Ā.⌀一愀琀椀瘀攀开一漀搀攀"):
>   Data type 0x52 is unknown.

The same error is throwing on methods without any parameters also. I am using .net 3.5 and Sql server 2008(10.50.4319.0)

Also this issue is not occurred every time while executing the queries. The same was occured once on my dev environment, but fixed some how. When I moved the source to another environment, the error is again throwing.

I have done some researches, but was in vain.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Which SQL Client version are you using and how are you connecting? Such errors may happen when you try to use incompatible driver versions. You'd have to be using the SQL Server 2000 driver though, or connecting to a SQL Server 2000 for such incompatibilities. Using the wrong OLEDB or ODBC driver may also be an issue